# loading bfile via SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, bfile

I am trying to load values into a table who's one of the columns is BFILE using SQL Loader.

My table looks like this:

```
create table documents 
    ( id number primary key
    , text bfile)
```

Here are my CTL adn DAT files:

loader.ctl

```
load data
infile d':\test\loader.dat'
into table documents
replace
fields terminated by ';'
    ( id integer
    , text bfilename('MY_DIRECTORY', 'my_file.txt') terminated by eof)
```

loader.dat

```
3;my_file.txt
```

When I execute sqlldr command with paramters above, I received the error message:

> SQL*Loader-350: Suntax error at line 7.
>
> Expecting "," or ")", found "bfilename".
>
> ```
>     , text bfilename('MY_DIRECTORY', 'my_file.txt') terminated by eof)
>
>     ^
> ```

Am I doing something wrong or SQL Loader do not accept BFILEs?

Thank you,

Comment: sorry, my mistake when posting rhe wrror messege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has [a section on loading BFILE columns](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-CA3B8A38-0559-4E34-A8FB-B4627A2AAF40.htm).

You need to have a filler column that will represent the filename field in your data file, and then refer to that filler field name in the `bfile()` - and not `bfilename()` - field definition:

```
load data
infile d:\test\loader.dat
into table documents
replace
fields terminated by ';'
    ( id
    , filename filler
    , text bfile(constant 'MY_DIRECTORY', filename) )
```

You don't want your `ID` field to be declared as `integer`; [this is a full-word binary integer](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-89EEFDF0-22B9-400B-B70A-45BACC41E911.htm), and you probably won't get the value you expect in your table column.

If you want to explicitly convert to a number you can do:

```
...
fields terminated by ';'
    ( id "to_number(:id)"
    , filename filler
    , text bfile(constant 'MY_DIRECTORY', filename) )
```

but implicit conversion will usually be OK too.

Comment: the solution is loading rows into the table but ... they do not seem to be linked to the physical location from the hard disk. When I browse the table and try to save one of the files, it gave me an error.

"java.lang.NullPointerException
 at oracle.dbtools.raptor.extendedtype.BFILEType.saveToDisk(BFILEType.java:106)
 at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.celleditor.ExtendedTypeEditPanel.saveToDisk(ExtendedTypeEditPanel.java:398)
 at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.celleditor.BFileEditPanel.processExtendedType(BFileEditPanel.java:192)"

Comment: " at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.celleditor.ResultSetCellEditor.showExtendedTypeEdit(ResultSetCellEditor.java:299)
 at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.celleditor.ResultSetCellEditor.access$200(ResultSetCellEditor.java:52)
 at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.celleditor.ResultSetCellEditor$1.actionPerformed(ResultSetCellEditor.java:140)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)"

Comment: " at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5517)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3135)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5282)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)"

Comment: "
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)

 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)"

Comment: " at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)"

Comment: That's a completely separate issue, so ask a new question that includes the Java code you're using. Or if your client is throwing that error, which client it is and exactly what you are doing.